# python translate bytecode to utf-8 using a variable

Tags: python-3.x, bytecode, pypyodbc

I have the following problem:

From a SQL Server database I am reading data using python module pypyodbc and ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server  and writing to txt files.

Database contains all kinds of special characters and they read as:

```
'PR\xc3\x86KVAL'
```

The `'\xc3\x86'` part is bytecode and should be interpreted that way. The other characters should be interpreted as shown. UTF8 would translate `'\xc3\x86'` to Æ.

If I type the value in `b'PR\xc3\x86KVAL'` , python recognizes it as bytecode and I can translate it to PRÆKVAL. See below:

```
s = b'PR\xc3\x86KVAL'
print(s)
bb = s.decode('utf-8')
print(bb)
```

The problem is that I don’t know how I can turn `'PR\xc3\x86KVAL’` to be recognized as a bytecode object.

I want the value that has to be decoded to be a variable so that all data from database can flow through it.

I Also tried `ast.literal_eval(r”b'PR\xc3\x86KVAL'”)`, but variables won’t work in this way.

Answer (score 2):

Since you start out with `PR\xc3\x86KVAL` as a *text string* and `decode` indeed expects a raw byte sequence, you need to convert the text string into a bytes object. But when converting from one "encoding" value to another, Python needs to know what encoding it is starting with!

The easiest way to do so is explicitly *encoding* the string, using an encoding that does not change the special characters. You must be careful, because it is very well possible that a character code might be translated to something else, destroying their meaning.

You can see that with a simple example: attempting to tell Python this should be plain ASCII fails, for an obvious reason.

```
>>> s = 'PR\xc3\x86KVAL'.encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Even though there are [more than 1,000 questions on Stack Overflow about this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+UnicodeEncodeError%3A+%27ascii%27+codec+can%27t+encode+characters), the reason for the failure should be easy to understand. All an encoder/decoder pair does is translate each character from 'source' to 'destination'. This can only work if the character in question actually *exists* in both the 'source' and 'destination' encodings. Suppose you want to translate a Greek character `β` to a Russian `б`, then the source *must* be able to decode the Greek character (because that is what you entered it in) and the destination *must* be able to encode the Russian character.

So you must be careful to choose an encoding which does not change the character `\x86` in your input string into `Ж` (which it would do when using `cp866`, for example).

Fortunately, as quoted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2617930/2564301, there is an encoding that does not mess up things:

> Pass `data.decode('latin1')` to the codec. `latin1` maps bytes 0-255 to Unicode characters 0-255, which is kinda elegant.

and so this should work:

```
>>> s = 'PR\xc3\x86KVAL'.encode('latin1')
>>> print(s)
b'PR\xc3\x86KVAL'
```

Now `s` is a properly encoded *byte* object, so you can decode it at will:

```
>>> bb = s.decode('utf-8')
>>> print(bb)
PRÆKVAL
```

Done!