# Error decoding byte string in Python3 [TypeError: must be str, not bytes]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, python-unicode

I'm trying to use in Python 3.6 a piece of code written for Python 2.7, and I'm having trouble managing differences in how byte strings are handled.
The code is meant to read a .dat file that existed before I wrote my code.
Running the untouched P2.7 script returns the following error:

```
import numpy as np

buff = ''
dt = np.dtype([('var1', np.uint32, 1), ('var2', np.uint8, 1)])

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        dat = line
--->    buff += dat

    data = np.frombuffer(buffer=buff, dtype=dt)

TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

If I get it right, while Python2 will concatenate the read bytes into the string buff without complaining, Python3 cares about the difference between bytes and strings.
Typecasting line to str(line) returns the following error:

```
    for line in f:
        dat = str(line)
        buff += dat
->  data = np.frombuffer(buffer=buff, dtype=dt)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__buffer__'
```

How should I go about it? What type should buff be?
Any solutions that would work for P2.7 and P3.6?

**EDIT**

It turns out the data in filename.dat is not made of unicode strings at all. I've edited the question to remove mention to my mistaken assumption, and I've added lines of code I'd omitted in trying to show a minimal example that I now realize are relevant. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: A large part of [an earlier answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749833/2564301) could be repeated here.

Comment: Do you want to maintain 2.x compatibility?

Comment: @usr2564301 Thanks for pointing out, but I have no control over how filename was encoded

Comment: @tdelaney That'd be preferred, but not essential

Comment: ... ? But you want to convert `line`, not `filename`.

Comment: @usr2564301 But line is an iteration over open(filename). I'm assuming the relevant encoding is not affected by how filename is opened, right?

Comment: You lost me there. "How filename is opened" -> it is passed to your OS. You read *bytes*; as said in that answer, "latin1" encodes 'raw' bytes to equivalent Unicodes. But where the bytes came from (i.e., what filename) is irrelevant.

Comment: If the you are decoding `line` one by one from a file, why won't you just open it in a regular text mode?

Comment: The real qeustion is what encoding is your file using?

Comment: Ok, here's a bummer: it turns out what I'm trying to decode aren't even strings in the first place, but an array (uint32, uint8) pairs. Confusion comes from variable buff being initialized as a string to which bytes were concatenated - which works in P2.7 but not in P3.6. I guess I don't need buff to be a string. I'm editing the question to add how is buff used.

Comment: Be careful, str(somebytes) yields a result that may surprise you and is not likely what you want: `b = b'xxx'; str(b)` -> `"b'xxx'"` whereas `b.decode('utf8')` -> `'xxx'` So you really want a decode method (which will give you unicode object in Py2, but should be OK for all practical intents and purposes. Or if no unicode is involved, use `ascii`  (or other suitable) encoding (you'll get just a plain string in both py2 and py3).

Answer (score 0):

Use `io.BytesIO` for your buffer. This is compatible with Python 2 and 3, and preferable to `str`/`bytes` concatenation for large datasets.

```py
import io

import numpy as np


buff = io.BytesIO()
dt = np.dtype([('var1', np.uint32, 1), ('var2', np.uint8, 1)])

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        buff.write(line)

    buff.seek(0)
    data = np.frombuffer(buffer=buff.read(), dtype=dt)
```